# Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/kushal/process.php

Tags: php

`

```
<?php
$param1=$_POST["n1"];
$param2=$_POST["n2"];
$param3=$_POST["n3"];
$param4=$_POST["n4"];
$param5=$_POST["n5"];
$param6=$_POST["n6"];

$tmp = exec ("/opt/lampp/htdocs/kushal/run.sh ".$param1." ".$param2." ".$param3." ".$param4." ".$param5." ".$param6, $array);

echo"<h1>Here is our output !!!<h1>";



echo "<h1>Contents of gypsum = ".$array[2]."<br/>";
echo "Contents of Fert N = ".$array[3]."<br/>";
echo "Contents of Fert P = ".$array[4]."<br/>";
echo "Contents of Fert K = ".$array[5]."<br/></h1>";


?>'
```

please help to remove error Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/kushal/process.php on line 14
i am running this on ubuntu using xampp

Comment: var_dump($array); what it prints?

Comment: try var_dump($array) to see the content of your array. It may help.

Comment: `$array` is array of single element. So `$array[2]`, `$array[3]` is invalid

Comment: var_dump($array) gives array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: running this (.sh) file in terminal while providing 6 parameters gives output

Comment: A good way to avoid these issues is to do this: `if (isset($_POST["n1"])) $param1 = $_POST["n1"];`

Comment: Try to add `$array = new array();` before `$tmp = exec ("/opt/lampp/...`,

Comment: tried all above but no success the same code works fine in windows but not in ubuntu